# How to get a list of highest values from another list in flutter

Tags: arrays, list, flutter, dart

I have a list of players consist of 5 objects..

```
"data": [
    {
      "id": 74,
      "name": "name 1",
      "type": "defender",
      "value": 10
    },
    {
      "id": 7422,
      "name": "name 2",
      "type": "defender",
      "value": 20
    },
    {
      "id": 2213,
      "name": "Max",
      "type": "defender",
      "value": 30
    },
    {
      "id": 3333,
      "name": "John",
      "type": "defender",
      "value": 40
    },
    {
      "id": 8793,
      "name": "Alex",
      "type": "defender",
      "value": 50
    }
  ]
```

How can I get a list consist of 3 items of the highest values from data list ?

expected results => [Max , John , Alex]

I need only the top 3 items based on highest value

Comment: you just wanna get 3 max value(actually object ) from json list or from flutter list?

Comment: Only taking 3 person which above value or below?

Comment: @Jigangsu from flutter list, I already parsed the json data into a flutter list, from this flutter list i want generate top 3 highest values

Comment: @ArbiterChil I need the highest values, please have a look at expected results

Comment: what you mean by generate? you have the list yes and you want to do is to pluck the highest value? is that what you mean? then that three value should only be shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First sort data based on value then find out the max value

```
void main() {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = [
    {"id": 74, "name": "name 1", "type": "defender", "value": 10},
    {"id": 7422, "name": "name 2", "type": "defender", "value": 20},
    {"id": 2213, "name": "Max", "type": "defender", "value": 30},
    {"id": 3333, "name": "John", "type": "defender", "value": 40},
    {"id": 8793, "name": "Alex", "type": "defender", "value": 50}
  ];



// sort the data based on 
  if (data != null && data.isNotEmpty) {
    data.sort((a, b) => a['value'].compareTo(b['value']));
  }
// you can simply do this
  for( int i =data.length-3; i< data.length;i++){
    print(data[i]["name"]);
  }
  

  // truncate the max value from the bottom part
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> data1 = data.sublist(data.length-3, data.length);
  
// show the data whom hold the max value
  data1.reversed.forEach((e){
    print(e["name"]);
  });
}
```

Output: Alex
John
Max

**N.B: you used reversed if you want to print from high to low after getting sorted value**

Comment: Legend!, any idea how can I get the smallest items ?

Comment: just print from top to bottom `for( int i =0; i< 3;i++){
    print(data[i]["name"]);
  }`

Answer (score 1):

```
        List<Map<String, dynamic>> users =[
    {
      "id": 74,
      "name": "name 1",
      "type": "defender",
      "value": 10
    },
    {
      "id": 7422,
      "name": "name 2",
      "type": "defender",
      "value": 20
    },
    {
      "id": 2213,
      "name": "Max",
      "type": "defender",
      "value": 30
    },
    {
      "id": 3333,
      "name": "John",
      "type": "defender",
      "value": 40
    },
    {
      "id": 8793,
      "name": "Alex",
      "type": "defender",
      "value": 50
    }
  ]


      if (users != null && users.isNotEmpty) {
      users.sort((a, b) => a['value'].compareTo(b['value']));
      print(users.last['value']);
```

> users list already sorted in above code. so last 3 items of the list are max value!

Comment: when it's not sorted then you must need to sorted first and then collect last three value, so it is safe too use sorted

Answer (score 1):

For me if you have a standard that the value is higher in 20 or 30

```
List<Map<String,dynamic>> items = [{
      "id": 74,
      "name": "name 1",
      "type": "defender",
      "value": 10
    },
    {
      "id": 7422,
      "name": "name 2",
      "type": "defender",
      "value": 20
    },
    {
      "id": 2213,
      "name": "Max",
      "type": "defender",
      "value": 30
    },
    {
      "id": 3333,
      "name": "John",
      "type": "defender",
      "value": 40
    },
    {
      "id": 8793,
      "name": "Alex",
      "type": "defender",
      "value": 50
    }];
```

then for sorting them is like this with where

```
items.where((e) => e['value'] > 20).toList()..sort((a,b)=>b['value'].toString().compareTo(a['value'].toString()));
```

and you will get a set of another data

```
[
{id: 8793, name: Alex, type: defender, value: 50}, 
{id: 3333, name: John, type: defender, value: 40}, 
{id: 2213, name: Max, type: defender, value: 30}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you sort this list by values and then take first three value from list.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please your answer in a way that adds value to the website. You have proposed what the accepted answer has with code. So, you should either delete it or improve it.